# Why aren't I receiving the UDP packets when using winsock?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, winsock

I am trying to write two programs, one that sends udp packets and one that receives them. My problem is that the receiving program isn't printing the packets even though wireshark shows that they are being sent to the right location.

Here is my code:
UDP_Send.cpp

```
    #include <WinSock2.h>
    #include <WS2tcpip.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    #define PORT_NUM "17140"

    int main()
    {
    int sock;
    addrinfo* sockInfo;
    addrinfo hints;

    //Initialize winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData))
        cout << "Error initializing winsock\n";

    //get the address info for the receiving end of this
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    if (getaddrinfo("192.168.1.9", PORT_NUM, &hints, &sockInfo) != 0)
    {
        cout << "Error getting the address info\n";
    }

    //Get the socket
    sock = socket(sockInfo->ai_family, sockInfo->ai_socktype, sockInfo->ai_protocol);
    if(sock == -1)
        cout<<"Error creating the socket\n";

    //Send the message to the receiver
    while (true)
    {
        string msg = "hello world";
        int i = sendto(sock, msg.c_str(), msg.length(), 0, sockInfo->ai_addr, sockInfo->ai_addrlen);
        if (i == -1)
            cout << "Error sending the packet\n";
    }

    //Clean up winsock
    WSACleanup();

    return 1;
    }
```

UDP_Receive.cpp

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define PORT_NUM "17140"

int main()
{
    int sock;
    addrinfo* sockInfo;
    addrinfo hints;

    //Initialize winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData))
        cout << "Error initalizing winsock\n";

    //Get the address info of this program
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_protocol = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    int check = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT_NUM, &hints, &sockInfo);
    if (check != 0)
        cout << WSAGetLastError();

    //Get the socket
    sock = socket(sockInfo->ai_family, sockInfo->ai_socktype, sockInfo->ai_protocol);
    if (sock == -1)
        cout << "Error creating the socket\n";

    //Bind to the socket
    if (bind(sock, sockInfo->ai_addr, sockInfo->ai_addrlen) == -1)
        cout << "Error creating the socket\n";

    //Recieve data from the socket
    while (true)
    {
        char msg[20];
        memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
        check = recvfrom(sock, msg, sizeof(msg), 0, NULL, NULL);
        cout << msg << endl;
    }

    WSACleanup();

    return 1;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: (1) Change `hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE` to `hints.ai_flags = IPPROTO_UDP`.(2) Change `socket(...)` to `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem, and it was just a simple mistake.

```
//Get the address info of this program
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_protocol = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
```

should be

```
//Get the address info of this program
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; //this is where the change is
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
```

Now it works.

Comment: Oh, man, I don't know you but I freaking LOVE you!!!  Pulling my hair for HOURS just to get a UDP receive to work, and after countless useless examples, this one DID IT!!!  You are da MAN!!!  Up-vote and big green CHECK!!!